# Error at json: "missing ] after element list" or just "undefined"

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json like:

```
 {"156644":{ "name":"name1",
           "street":"street1",
           "city":"city1"
 "68656":{  "name":"name2 ",
           "street":"street2",
           "city":"city1"
 "388655":{ "name":"name3",
           "street":"street3",
           "city":"city1"
 "4564":{  "name":"name4",
           "street":"street4",
           "city":"city1"
 "6333":{  "name":"name5",
           "street":"street5",
           "city":"city1"}}
```

Now I want to decode this json. In my Javascript I wrote:

```
        var object = eval(obj_json);
        if(typeof(object)!="undefined"){
            //fuel
            for (var ii=0; ii<object.length; ii++){
                alert(ii)
            }
        }
```

Now I get an Undefined error at object.length. So I tried to parse my json like:

```
var object = eval(' (' + obj_json + ') '); alert(object.length);
```

but this doesn't work at all.
Now I get an "missing ] after element list" error.

Can U help me? PLZ!

Comment: Is it just me, or are you missing closing braces and commas?

Comment: Well, guess it's not just me then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btw: I fixed this Problem by coding:

```
eval("var jsonobject=" + obj_json);
```

now it works! Now I can write:

```
for(ii in jsonobject){
    var intii = parseInt(ii);
    if (!isNaN(intii)){
        var street = jsonobject[ii].street;
        alert(street)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing closing brackets after each element:

```
 {"156644":{ "name":"name1",
           "street":"street1",
           "city":"city1"       // Bracket needs to be here!
 "68656":{  "name":"name2 ",
           "street":"street2",
           "city":"city1"       // Bracket needs to be here!
// ...
```

Instead, it should probably look like:

```
 {"156644":{ "name":"name1",
           "street":"street1",
           "city":"city1"},
 "68656":{  "name":"name2 ",
           "street":"street2",
           "city":"city1"},
 // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing closing `}` thingies all over the place. Didn't you mean this:

```
 {"156644":{ "name":"name1",
           "street":"street1",
           "city":"city1" }, // THIS, RIGHT HERE
 "68656":{  "name":"name2 ",
           "street":"street2",
           "city":"city1" }, // AND THIS
 "388655":{ "name":"name3",
           "street":"street3",
           "city":"city1" }, // AND THIS
 "4564":{  "name":"name4",
           "street":"street4",
           "city":"city1" }, // AND THIS
 "6333":{  "name":"name5",
           "street":"street5",
           "city":"city1"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking out any suggestions as to the problem, as the OP's two postings have different content. But still recommending  [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

Comment: OP did try your second `eval` example (see the bottom of the question).

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that. But I did just notice the real problem.

Comment: OP *is* using strings as keys. They just happen to contain numeric values :)

Comment: @kdgregory: ah, right. Still, JavaScript converts keys to strings. Eg `({ 12345:'foo' })["12345"]` still results in output `"foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

If that is an exact dump of your JSON, then your problem is with your var names;

Your JSON provider needs to change their output, or you need to parse it before you try to decode it, to get proper var names in there:

`json=eval( obj_json.replace( /([, \n\r\t])([0-9]*):/g, '$1"v_$2":' ) );`

(not rigorously tested, just an example that works on the example code)